# OpenVPN and Iptables

Tags: iptables, openvpn

I see a few articles on this already but my situation is slightly different.

What I would like to do is create **VPN tunnels** between my cloud VM instances running CentOS 7. They each have a static public IP and one interface.

My goal is to have my mysql servers talking (replicating in both directions) over an encrypted session and have the mysql server listen on a dummy interface I create with private IP address (yes I realize mysql already supports encryption by default but I want other apps to talk over the tunnel as well so I don't have to maintain separate keys/sessions for every application).

I know how IPSEC works on a Cisco/Juniper/etc router/firewall but `Openvpn` may be a little different.

On site to site VPNs, for the SA to form you must associate an inside subnet/ACL for everything to work.

Is the dummy interface required for this and what does the NAT tables need to look like if I say have a dummy interface with 172.31.254.1/24 address on it and have this subnet defined in my openvpn config?

Is this the right way to do this or is there a better way?

TIA!

Comment: OpenVPN isn't IPSec. You can have either. Which do you want?

Comment: In this instance, whatever OpenVPN is based on will work. In the near future I need to be able to have firewalls connect to these servers as well so if OpenVPN cannot do IPSEC, I need to find another solution.

Comment: You can use OpenVPN to join LANs and you can use IPSec to join LANs. But you can't have OpenVPN running IPSec. My Sophos firewalls do OpenVPN and IPSec so including firewalls in an OpenVPN mesh isn't necessarily an impossibility. I'd suggest you do some research...

Comment: Ok, that makes sense as to why the typical IPSEC params weren't in the server.conf file for OpenVPN. OpenVPN will work fine for the server to server traffic and I'll just add the usual vendor VPN client to the servers should they need to access any firewalls. So any suggestions as to what the NAT table needs to look like provided I use the same info as the main part of my post?

Comment: I don't understand why you'd want NAT anywhere in this setup.

Comment: Some of the VM's I have are running in clouds and they use private IPs directly on the VM's and filter any public IPs assigned to the server but they are NAT'd and it's something I must deal with. Otherwise I would agree to just use public's but in my case, NAT is a necessary evil.

Comment: Ok. A couple of thoughts then. 1. Fix your question so you stop referring to OpenVPN IPSec, because there is no such thing. 2. Describe your topology, if necessary inventing some appropriate IP address and port ranges. This will give a structure on which someone can build a relevant answer, and you can then map the answers using your fictional topology back to your real world requirement.

Comment: Ok, wording has been fixed. And my topology is very simple, it's a hub and spoke topology on the internet. One server will be the hub and all others will connect to it via VPN so that replication can happen from the spokes to the hub. If I can get the hub IPtables config, I should be able to get the rest of the spokes based on the hub config.

Answer (score 0):

OpenVPN encapsulates traffic. Since you say you're planning to use hub-and-spoke you can set up the hub as the OpenVPN Server and the spokes as OpenVPN Clients. (You could equally set up a peer-to-peer mesh if that worked better for your topology.)

Let's assume Client/Server.

Run OpenVPN over its default UDP/1194. Allow that in to the Server with an `iptables ... -j ACCEPT` rule. Make sure you can also send corresponding traffic out again. Allow UDP/1194 out from each Client to the Server, and corresponding traffic back in again.

Configure OpenVPN according to its Client/Server example. Make sure you're routing'(the default) and not bridging.

- https://superuser.com/q/1234518/332907
- https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/RoutedLans